# Addition of Date attribute column into Existing MULTISET VOLATILE TABL

Tags: database, stored-procedures, teradata, data-manipulation, data-modeling

I have a existing table with column which shows the Product Age based on CASE statements. I want to add a new column with Date attribute to show the Datetime of product registration based on Product Age column into same dataset (MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE)

Tried with Altering but table but the script contains SPs with Case statements. Need some SQL function to adjust in SP and continue with addition of new column

Comment: Volatile Tables don't support adding colums. Why don't you simply calculate the age in your Select?